# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html" in React with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, deployment

During deployment I'm facing the above error, hard refresh fix the issue after the deployment. Build is created in a subfolder named v2 inside dist folder

my nginx file looks like this

```js
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /tools/dist;

    location / {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html;
    }
}
```